# render :js not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render

I am working on window 7  and facing issue with render

```
render :js => "alert('Hello')".
```

But it is not getting alert.

Do any one have experience with this issue.

Comment: Please show your controller-method and the ajax call. The fact that it runs on windows is not relevant at all for this problem.

Comment: request is going to xyz method but i have added a before filter that have the render code:  def session_expiry

  render :js=> "alert('Mine method')"  ,:content_type => 'text/javascript'

Answer (score 2):

You should make the call using AJAX so you should add the param "remote: true" to the link or form that is making the call to that action

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that there is client side requested with JS format, as in that cases Rails set up content type for js, and not `text/html`.

Comment: In any case I am not getting alert I tried with asynchronous and synchronous request.I'm using window machine.

Comment: Check the request response in browser. If it `text/html` then your client code sending request with invalid content type. For example in jQuery on `ajax` you can specify the `dataType` see (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) [http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/]

Comment: I changed it to content_type=>application/x-javascript

Comment: also did :
render :js=> "alert('Mine method')" ,:content_type => 'text/javascript' 
I am using backbone framework !

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to debug your code. Using a `before_filter` is not the best way. A request can only render once.

I suggest adding statements to your logging, and using the javascript/development console of your browser (Chrome/Firefox): this will show what goes over the wire perfectly,a dn what is executed on the client, and why it fails (if it fails).

Hope this helps.

Comment: No I am not debug my code,See a request goes to an MyController's method that is create,but I have added a before_filer :check_active_time
check_active_time has render :js=>"alert('hello')",and this process done by ajax.so this is the scenario...Please help me if any..

Comment: 1) I believe a render in a `before_filter` is just wrong! 2) Use the tools I stated to search for the error, or show more code. The `render :js` will only work if your ajax is correct, as @MarkGut says.

Comment: Well I understand but MY need is like it i have to redirect to login page if user idle for 30min. and all pages working fine with redirect_to but some pages has only ajax (using backbone),so I need render for ajax requests...I have no choice ,If you have better Idea Please let me know